# Finding the unit

Tags: unit-of-measure

I have the equation: [image]

And the following units:

for `time` is the `day`

for the `alfa` and `p` is `day^(-1)`

for `S, s(i) and k` is `u*mol/L`

for `X` is `mm^3/L`

I have to find the unit for `y` but I don't know how to do that, I tried by writing the equation only with units but when to simpify it gives me a strange unit.

Comment: what is the unit of X?

Comment: @Atbey sorry, I forgot, mm^3/L

Comment: Hint: $\,S/(S+k)\,$ is adimensional, thus $\,\rho X / y\,$ has the same dimension as $\,S / t\,$.

Comment: @dxiv I tried that now and it gives me: `(mm^3) / (day * L) * 1 / y = (u * mol) / (L * day)`. I don't know how to find y from here

Comment: So you've got something like $\,a / y = b\,$, all that's left is to write $\,y = a / b\,$ and simplify.

Comment: @dxiv so it's correct `y= umol/mm^3` ? it's a strange unit :))

Comment: `y= umol/mm^3` No, that would be $\,1/y\,$ instead.